# CSS remove white space in between header and jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a designing a website where I would like the header to have a height of **100px** and a **jQuery slider** beneath it.  I have decided to use the **Jssor Slider** since I like the way it performs.  When I run my site, as I increase the width of the browser window, the slider container is increasing the amount of white space below the header.

I'm not really sure why this is occurring and I have tried playing around with the CSS by putting in **white-space:nowrap** & **display:inline-block** within the slider container itself but that's still not working.

HTML:

```
<header>
<!-- Header elements inside here -->
</header>

<!--Begin Jssor Slider -->

<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;white-space:nowrap;display:inline-block;">


    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 150px; width: 1300px;
        height: 600px; overflow: hidden;">
<!--Additional Slider divs for containing pictures, arrows, etc. -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background: #FFF;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Excuse me, but...it would help a lot if you could reproduce this into a jsfiddle of show the website at least...there are too many variables in between to be able to give a good answer...

Comment: @Allin Ok, give me a few minutes.  I'll put up a link to the site.

Comment: @Allin I actually figured out what was wrong.  After doing some testing, I found that for the actual slides container within one of the inner divs, I had "top:150px;".  After changing it to "top:0px;" there is no longer any space between the header and the slider.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't at the PC till this morning, this means that Bryce Siedschlaw had the good answer :) Anyway, glad it all worked out, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your slider is absolutely positioned. Why not decrease the `top` attribute to something like `top:100px;` ? You can decrease/increase it to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I just realized that you used `display:inline-block;`,this is what is causing your margin, you can either remove it, change it to `display:table;` or give a negative margin of -4px that will eliminate the blank space in between. You may need to adjust that negative margin according to your need but it will do the trick.

You can find more about [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements HERE](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: I tried that and its still increasing the amount of white space between the 2 divs.

Comment: I recommend not using negative margins. It can mess with different features of your site (especially, zooming functionality and mobile devices).

Comment: @bryceSiedschlaw I agree, changing the display attribute will do him best. .Also, regarding your answer, even though the slider is position absolute, the container of the slider is positioned relative.

Comment: @Alin, I wasn't sure if he was experiencing the issue between the header and the container div or the header and the inner div. I assumed it was between the inner div and the header since the header is fixed positioned and will always overlay the container with the given html

Comment: @bryceSiedschlaw Well, you covered that area ^^ I didn't thought about that part and thought the inline-block would be the problem :-?? Come to think of it, about this, the question isn't quite specific.